# What is the meaning of うなじや in the following passage?

Tags: translation, meaning, usage

> 雪乃の汗で濡れ光っている白い**うなじや**、上衣の合わせ目から覗くほっそりとした鎖骨は、清楚な容貌とは裏腹に淫靡な色香を漂わせている。

what does うなじや mean here  ?

> 清楚な容貌とは**裏腹に**淫靡な色香を漂わせている。

Also what does 裏腹に refer to  in this context?

Comment: Hello! You don't need to put the whole quote in italics, I recommend you to use italics/bold only to highlight certain parts of the quoted sentence. If not, it just makes the whole sentence less readable and it is superfluous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- うなじや is [うなじ](https://jisho.org/word/%E9%A0%85) ("nape") + や ("and"). うなじ and 鎖骨 are the subjects of the sentence. The simplified version of the sentence is うなじや鎖骨は色香を漂わせている.
- ～とは裏腹に is an adverbial set phrase, "despite ～", "in contrast to ～", "contrary to ～".

So the sentence is basically saying that although her overall appearance is clean, her うなじ and 鎖骨 are voluptuous.